# Could the federal government ban people from drinking coffee?

Tags: united-states, constitutional-law, legal-history

Which amendment does this statement violate?

The federal government refuses to allow anyone to drink coffee.

Comment: Is this homework?  What research of your own have you done towards answering the question?

Comment: Anyhow, what makes you so sure that this would violate any amendment?

Comment: Tagging this [tag:united-states] based on a guess that you're talking about the US.  Please change if not, and please use appropriate jurisdiction tags on future questions.

Comment: I am not sure if the courts would prevent Congress and or the regulatory agencies from banning the consumption of coffee; but I am very sure the people would not stand for it and such legislators and regulators would have short tenures.

Comment: I recommend reading the 18th amendment.

Comment: Many things that would be highly unpopular/ stupid / self destructive are legal.

Comment: As an interesting aside, the [Psychoactive Substances Act 2016](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2016/2/contents/enacted) in the UK has an exemption provision partially because if enacted without it, products like coffee, chocolate, and many OTC painkillers would be illegal, as caffeine is considered psychoactive (along with tobacco, alcohol and others).

Comment: In practical terms, the US government has attempted to ban a very popular drink once before.

Comment: @ChrisPetheram excellent point - in short it was legal, but not long-lived and made some people very rich.

Comment: The 21st amendment repealed the 18th, but also bans the transport of "intoxicating liquors"... in violation of state laws.  While this is referring mainly to alcohol (as per the primary definition per the Googles), I do note that the 2nd defintion of intoxicating is "exhilarating or exciting" and arguably coffee (or at least a triple shot of espresso) could qualify... so congress couldn't unilaterally ban coffee but individual states arguably could ban coffee if someone wanted to try to force a ruling of what constitutes "intoxicating"

Comment: I suspect the question is actually intended to be about [substantive due process on drugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legality_of_the_War_on_Drugs#Substantive_due_process).

Answer (score 44):

None. The federal government is allowed to prohibit coffee drinking under its power to regulate interstate commerce. Prohibition would not have required a constitutional amendment under modern constitutional jurisprudence either. By analogy, this would be no different (constitutionally) than a law prohibiting putting lithium in sodas (something that used to be done in *7 Up*) or putting cocaine in sodas (something that used to be done in *Coca-Cola*).

Conceivably, the law might have to allow a religious exemption in certain circumstances under the 1st Amendment's free exercise clause, but while many faiths prohibit drinking coffee (most notably, offshoots of The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints), none of which I am aware require it as a matter of religious doctrine sincerely espoused.

Comment: I was going to answer along the same lines, but then I wondered whether Congress can actually prohibit coffee *consumption*. They could prohibit trading in coffee under the Commerce Clause, but does that necessarily entail the power to prohibit drinking it?

Comment: Exactly, they couldn't just wake up one morning and decide that no one can drink coffee anymore.

Comment: Commerce Clause prohibitions can extend to grow-your-own and any form of consumption, because commerce *affects* interstate commerce.

Comment: Lots of case law (e.g. controlled substances act litigation) backs up @user6726 here.

Comment: Ahh, the interstate commerce clause, which has basically turned into the "yeah, the government can do anything it wants because basically anything at all affects interstate commerce" clause as its scope keeps on growing...

Comment: "Prohibition would not have required a constitutional amendment under modern constitutional jurisprudence either." I'm pretty sure that a constitutional amendment would still be required to ban alcohol to avoid it getting overturned for violating the First Amendment's protection of freedom of religion - Catholics drink wine during their rites.

Comment: @nick012000 what if my religious rites involve slavery?

Comment: @nick012000 Employment Division v. Smith 494 U.S. 872 (1990). On the federal level, Congress later passed RFRA, but these are acts of congress. So the ruling on the Fist Amendment issue holds.

Comment: Coca Cola to this day actually still uses (spent) coca leaves in their production as a flavoring element, so arguably it still does contain *very small* amounts of cocaine.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman at least wikipedia's summary says they extract substances from coca leaves to use as a flavouring agent and sell the cocaine to a pharmaceutical company, so I'd guess the amount of cocaine actually ending up in the drink is unmeasurably low. Didn't actually know they still used coca at all, though

Comment: @rand337 Thanks for the edit, no offense towards the members of that faith were intended by my mangling of the exact name of the denomination and capitalization issues there.

Comment: Wait, if I grow and consume coffee in the same state what does it have to do with interstate commerce?

Comment: Try reading the other answer as well, and the comments on both. *Gonzales* is your keyword. @candied_orange

Comment: Please explain to me why they needed a constitutional amendment to ban one drug, alcohol, but not every other drug?

Comment: @johndoe The particularly expansive application of the Commerce Clause began after Prohibition was repealed. Read the third sentence of this answer again. The 18A didn't ban personal consumption either, which Congress does now ban without any amendment for several drugs.

Comment: Could you add a discussion of the compelling state interest test? The question seems to ask whether congress has the power to ban coffee arbitrarily.

Comment: @David42 The compelling state interest test isn't applicable. This decision is subject to rational basis review except to the extend that there is a bona fide free exercise claim which there is no reason to believe will be presented. Congress can ban coffee for the most arbitrary and flimsy of reasons since this does not impact any constitutional right.

Answer (score 25):

This would almost certainly be within Congress's powers under the [Commerce Clause](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/commerce_clause), which has been interpreted quite broadly to encompass virtually anything someone could imagine *possibly* affecting interstate commerce, even indirectly.

There are two particularly on-point Supreme Court cases: [*Gonzales v. Raich*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gonzales_v._Raich) in 2005 and [*Wickard v. Filburn*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wickard_v._Filburn) in 1942.  *Gonzales v. Raich* held that Congress could prohibit the use of cannabis within a state (even if it never crossed state lines), because it could affect interstate demand for cannabis.  It was based in part on *Wickard v. Filburn*, which held that Congress could prohibit a farmer from growing wheat in excess of specified quotas (even if he never sold that wheat and only used it to feed his own animals), because he would otherwise have to purchase feed, which affects the interstate market for that.

To quote the court in *Gonzales*:

> In both cases, the regulation is squarely within Congress’ commerce power because production of the commodity meant for home consumption, be it wheat or marijuana, has a substantial effect on supply and demand in the national market for that commodity.

The only remaining obstacle would be that the government would have to articulate some rational basis for this law.  The [rational basis test](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/rational_basis_test) is the test for the constitutionality of a law in which no fundamental rights or equal-protection violations are at issue.  Since banning coffee consumption (probably) doesn't implicate any fundamental rights or discriminate against any protected class of people, it would apply here. It requires 1) that the law advance a legitimate state interest, and 2) that there be a rational connection between that goal and the means by which the law attempts to advance it.

That's not a difficult bar to meet: one possible reason would be that it contains caffeine, an addictive drug that has negative health implications when consumed in excess.  Protecting the health of the public would be a legitimate state interest, and restricting the consumption of a harmful substance would advance it.

Comment: Re: your last paragraph:  Is there any legal reason why the government has to "articulate a reasonable basis" for a law?  In general, giving such reasons is necessary *politically*;  but I didn't think that a law enacted for "no good reason" could be challenged in court solely on that basis.

Comment: As a layman (and a non-American layman to boot), I find it difficult to understand the logic that allows the Federal government to argue both that it has the duty to stamp out a certain kind of interstate commerce and that private production and consumption should be forbidden because it risks disrupting interstate commerce.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd The reasoning for *Gonzales* was not that a personal grow might *disrupt* interstate commerce, the issue was that it might *allow* it, frustrating federal attempts to regulate the interstate black market. "Congress may regulate noneconomic intrastate activities only where the failure to do so could undercut its regulation of interstate commerce." Banning personal medical grows was determined to be a permissible way of preventing access to marijuana for other uses.

Comment: @NuclearWang: IMHO, the question of whether some *particular* action interferes with federal efforts to regulate interstate commerce should, like many things over which the Court has usurped authority, be recognized as involving issues of both fact and law.  If the federal government can show that someone was acting with, at best, wanton disregard for whether their actions might interfere with federal interstate regulatory authority, that should be sufficient to merit federal jurisdiction; in most cases, that would probably be fairly easy to show.

Comment: @NuclearWang: If, however, the government is unable to convince a jury that someone growing plants for their own personal use was demonstrating such wanton disregard, it would have no basis for prosecution.  IMHO, many issues should be resolved by allowing juries to decide whether things that are *generally* true are in fact true of the *particular* case before them.

Comment: This is why I regard _Wickard_ as the very worst SCOTUS decision still in force (_Dred Scott_ and _Plessy v. Ferguson_ were worse, but those are no longer in effect).

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Good question.  I actually meant to write "_rational_ basis" instead of "reasonable," which is the most lenient test for the constitutionality of laws/regulations.  I updated my answer to expand on that a bit.

Comment: I think you've left an important part out of your discussion of the rational basis test: factual findings. While coffee does contain caffeine, it doesn't contain nearly enough for its wide availability to be considered a hazard from which the state may choose to protect the public. On top of that numerous studies have shown an inverse relationship between levels of coffee consumption and all-cause mortality. You should explain that your sample argument, while logical and complete in structure, fails hard on the facts. It seems to me then that the answer to the question as a whole must be "no".

Comment: @David42 Rational basis review does not actually require that the rationale be _accurate_, merely that it be _arguable_. See, e.g., [FCC v. Beach Communications, Inc.](//oyez.org/cases/1992/92-603): "The assumptions underlying these rationales may be erroneous, but the very fact that they are 'arguable' is sufficient, on rational-basis review, to 'immuniz[e]' the congressional choice from constitutional challenge." As Justice Stevens (quoting Justice Marshall) [wrote](//supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/552/196/): "The Constitution does not prohibit legislatures from enacting stupid laws."

Comment: @RyanM That is fascinating. How far does this extend, is there case law? The coffee-is-dangerous argument is only one step away from pure fiction. Can they go all the way? Can they require us to all wear red tee-shirts on Friday to frighten away the killer bats?

Answer (score -2):

If Congress bans coffee, the power has to be from some sources found in the constitution. The only conceivable source is the commerce clause. Thus, like other answers, I would focus on whether Congress would exceed its authority under the commerce clause.

Before I get into the details, I would like to clarify a common misconception, especially in the context of the commerce clause: If the US Supreme Court is not willing to declare a law unconstitutional, it is constitutional. This is not true. In other words, Ryan M has given an expansive answer on

> Would the Supreme Court declare the law unconstitutional?

but not

> Is the law unconstitutional?

Given that the Supreme Court only loosely examines Congress' commerce clause power (see below and Ryan M's answer), we must keep in mind that the answer to the first question can depart significantly from the second.

#### Background: Supreme Court's Spectrum of Interfering Other Governmental Branches (e.g., Level of Scrutiny)

In a democratic society with multiple government branches interacting with each other, when analyzing constitutional questions, the Supreme Court must consider whether it has the proper role to review and how much it may properly review, via interpreting its role defined in the Constitution. Interactions between governmental branches are about "ambitions counteracting ambitions," not "Supreme Court counteracting ambitions." If the Supreme Court police every single constitutional question in the utmost detail and interpret the constitution as expansive as it can, the government is, at least, close to a dictatorship and all other branches are the unelected Court's subordinates.

The Supreme Court has employed a spectrum of how much it would interfere with other branches of the government's actions. This includes the so-called "level of scrutiny." At one extreme end, the Supreme Court employs [strict scrutiny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_scrutiny): Federal courts should take close scrutiny at this kind of disputes and actively police whether the government has violated the constitution. Examples of such government actions include opinion-based speech regulation, laws that discriminate based on race, etc. These commonly involve issues that are susceptible to "tyranny of majority," such as fundamental right invasion and discrimination against minority. Federal Courts, less influenced by votes, are in a position to guard these interest.

At the other extreme end, the Supreme Court would deem an issue as not [justiciable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justiciability) — in other words, the Supreme Court deems the issue is inappropriate for federal courts to issue opinions, even if there is text on point written in the Constitution. For example, the Supreme Court has never answered the question whether the president can send troops to foreign land without a congressional war declaration, while Article I, Section 8 grants the Congress war declaration power. In fact, this question likely fits into the Court's [political question doctrine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_question#Doctrine). Does this mean this is constitutional? Instead, Congress passed the [War Powers Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_Powers_Resolution), which, in some sense, can be seen as Congress deeming some prior president's (especially Nixon's) war acts unconstitutional.

#### Supreme Court on the Commerce Clause

Regarding the commerce clause, the Supreme Court currently employs [rational basis test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_basis_review), with some qualifications (noticeably United States v. Lopez, 514 U.S. 549 (1995) and United States v. Morrison, 529 U.S. 598 (2000)). This means that Supreme Court puts commerce clause-related questions closer to the nonjusticiable side of the spectrum. Ryan M's answer is the one that applies rational basis test to the OP's question. As a result, the Supreme Court would unlikely declare this ban unconstitutional. But keep in mind that the Court has never said Congress has unlimited power under the commerce clause.

#### Who Should Police Congressional Exercise of the Commerce Clause?

Chief Justice Marshall once wrote:

> If, as has always been understood, the sovereignty of Congress, though limited to specified objects, is plenary as to those objects, the power over commerce with foreign nations, and among the several States, is vested in Congress as absolutely as it would be in a single government, having in its Constitution the same restrictions on the exercise of the power as are found in the Constitution of the United States. The wisdom and the discretion of Congress, their identity with the people, and the influence which their constituents possess at elections are, in this, as in many other instances, as that, for example, of declaring war, the sole restraints on which they have relied, to secure them from its abuse. They are the restraints on which the people must often rely solely, in all representative governments.

Gibbons v. Ogden, 22 U.S. 1 (1824). Basically, *Ogden*'s view is that the restraint on the Congress' exercise of the commerce clause is not from federal judiciary; it is from the political process. Wickard v. Filburn, 317 U.S. 111 (1942) explained:

> [Chief Justice Marshall] made emphatic the embracing and penetrating nature of this power by warning that effective restraints on its exercise must proceed from political, rather than from judicial, processes.

The Supreme Court's current view largely follows the *Gibbons* line. See e.g., Atlanta Motel v. United States, 379 U.S. 241 (1964) ("The principles which we apply today are those first formulated by Chief Justice Marshall in *Gibbons*).

According to these opinions, it is likely difficult to find the answer to the OP's question in Court's decisions. **The answer likely lies in the political process**.

This sort of makes sense, because commerce regulations are complicated and federal courts are poorly equipped to police these regulations. Unlike fundamental right questions, tyranny of majority also rarely finds home in these regulations. (Of course, people have different opinions regarding whether the Supreme Court is too hands-off or not. But as it currently stands, political process should lead to the answer.)

#### How Does the Political Process Restrain Congress from Abusing Its Commerce Power?

Justice Breyer explained:

> ... [W]ithin the bounds of the rational, Congress, not the courts, must remain primarily responsible for striking the appropriate state/federal balance. Garcia v. San Antonio Metropolitan Transit Authority, 469 U.S. 528, 552 (1985); ante, at 19-24 ( Souter, J., dissenting); Kimel v. Florida Bd. of Regents, 528 U.S. 94-94, (2000) ( Stevens, J., dissenting) (Framers designed important structural safeguards to ensure that, when Congress legislates, "the normal operation of the legislative process itself would adequately defend state interests from undue infringement"); see also Kramer, Putting the Politics Back into the Political Safeguards of Federalism, 100 Colum. L. Rev. 215 (2000) (focusing on role of political process and political parties in protecting state interests). Congress is institutionally motivated to do so. Its Members represent state and local district interests. They consider the views of state and local officials when they legislate, and they have even developed formal procedures to ensure that such consideration takes place. See, e.g., Unfunded Mandates Reform Act of 1995, Pub.L. 104-4, 109 Stat. 48 (codified in scattered sections of 2 U.S.C.). Moreover, Congress often can better reflect state concerns for autonomy in the details of sophisticated statutory schemes than can the Judiciary, which cannot easily gather the relevant facts and which must apply more general legal rules and categories. See, e.g., 42 U.S.C. § 7543 (b) (Clean Air Act); 33 U.S.C. § 1251 et seq. (Clean Water Act); see also New York v. United States, 505 U.S. 144, 167-168 (1992) (collecting other examples of "cooperative federalism"). Not surprisingly, the bulk of American law is still state law, and overwhelmingly so.

U.S. v. Morrison, 529 U.S. 598 (2000) (Breyer, J., dissenting). *Garcia*, cited in the passage above, lists some additional examples on how the states would restrain Congress. For example, States have the power to regulate the perhaps most two important aspects of federal election: Districting and voter qualifications; large amount of federal revenue flows to states, meaning that states have effective control over some federal policy execution (keep in mind that an increase in federal taxation generally negatively impacts votes).

#### So, Is It Constitutional?

According to the above analysis and Supreme Court's previous opinions, the question is more about political process and less about Court opinion analysis. Here, I'm attempting to make a guess on whether the political process would likely restrain Congress from enacting such a law.

The OP provides too little context, and it's difficult to know whether a ban on coffee is truly about "interstate commerce". If coffee has turned out to be something similar to cocaine, then I think it is constitutional. Coffee has an established national market, and to eliminate coffee from the national market, it is necessary to prohibit on the consumption side. Individual states are unlikely able to effectively ban coffee, they would also unlikely oppose this coffee ban. In fact, they may also likely cooperate with the ban: receive federal fund and execute the ban. Given these factors, voters are unlikely voting these Congressmen out of their seats.

Now let's take a different assumption of the facts. Unlike other states, the state of Coffee Fan is plagued with the issue of coffee overdrinking -- 10% of its population drink over one ton of coffee per day. One option is for the state to ban coffee completely because there's no other practical way to administrate the law (for the sake of argument). The point of the law is not about interstate commerce; it is about the market within the state of Coffee Fan alone. In the OP's hypothetical, Congress, instead of the state, plan on enacting such a law. The political process would likely restrain Congress from enacting such a law, because the overwhelming majority of the population in other states still enjoy coffee in benign doses. These state governments also would unlikely cooperate. The 90% of the population in the state of Coffee Fan would also likely oppose, because it becomes more difficult for them to adjust the policy in the future in response to the changes of their local problems.

Comment: I can foresee some folks might tempt to mark this answer as "not law-related". This is law related, heavily involving interpretation of the Constitution. This is simply not litigation-focused.

Comment: This analysis is basically wrong. You are right that it is a rational basis analysis (which is basically meaningless) under the Interstate Commerce Clause. But your alleged category of unconstitutional but non-justiciable legislation is dubious at best. And states have no role in the federal political process. You are misreading *Garcia*.

Comment: @ohwilleke You said I was misreading Garcia, but your statement is plainly contrary to the highlighted text in my quote of Garcia.

Comment: What you are missing is that the employees in *Garcia* were state government owned corporation transit employees who were federal grant funded, so the primary issue was the extent to which the federal government can meddle in the operations of state and local governments. Pre-Garcia state and local government employees couldn't be regulated at all on federalism grounds. This carved out an exception to the old rule. The state participation issue comes up only because of those details and isn't generally a part of commerce clause analysis. "Destructive to state sovereignty" was the new test.

Comment: @ohwilleke I agree that my answer centered too much on Garcia, which should be supportive rather than central to the argument. Putting Garcia in the center would actually distort the meaning of Garcia's text. I updated the answer to change the analysis from centering on states' countervailing power to political process in general.

Comment: @ohwilleke For your doubts on the non-justiciable legislation, if you refer to the war power example, it serves as an example of the theme of that section: the Court is not always suitable in policing every single area touched by the Constitution. I think the example is illustrative, because it demonstrated an interaction between branches of governments that does not involve the federal judiciary: it was Congress, not the Court, that responded to the President's war acts by increasing restraints.

Comment: @ohwilleke Additionally, the statement that "states have no role in the federal political process" is still contrary to Garcia and the political reality, regardless of how the other arguments go (in addition to what's listed in the text, there are informal ones such as state officials running for Congress seats).